# Immutable Borrows for the Same Data Structure

Tags: rust

I'm trying to call the "splice" method twice on the same vec.

I'm aware why it fails: the rules make sense. What I don't know is how to accomplish what I want. Is there a way to prove to the compiler that nothing will go wrong?

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let y = x.splice(2.., []);
    let z = x.splice(2.., []);
    println!("{:?}", x);
    println!("{:?}", y);
    println!("{:?}", z);
}
```

Comment: What should be the desired output? As written, `z` would be guaranteed to be empty, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove that nothing will go wrong with your code, because with something *will* go wrong the way you have this written!

The value returned by `splice()` is a bit special.  It's a [`Splice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Splice.html) struct.  The vector still owns the elements you asked it to remove immediately after `splice()` returns.

`Splice` is an `Iterator`.  When you iterate it, it moves the values out of the original vector to produce them.

When the `Splice` value is dropped, the replacement items are enumerated and moved into the vector.  So while the `Splice` exists, the splice operation is in a partially-completed state.

Now it should be clear why you can't call `.splice()` again while a `Splice` from the same vector still exists -- the vector is still mutably borrowed, because the splice isn't complete.

To fix your problem, you need to drop any extant `Splice` value before attempting to do anything else with the vector.  It looks like you want to move the removed elements into a new vector, so you can just `.collect()` the `Splice`s.  Doing this in a single statement drops the `Splice` at the end of the statement, because it is a temporary.

```
    let y = x.splice(2.., []).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let z = x.splice(2.., []).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e248fcc1a40bb3ed556721299a6ea139))

Comment: Is there a single function that will do `x.splice(...).collect::<Vec<_>>();`? It's rather verbose.

Comment: @Test No, but you can write your own.

Comment: How does one do so? Do you mean contribute to the standard library? If not, how does one add a method to an existing data structure via an external library?

Comment: @Test You can either write an extension trait and implement it on `Vec` or you can just write a free function and invoke it without using method syntax.

Comment: Ok, I've added a question about how to define an extension trait via an external module.